# Splitting data stored in dictionary to train, validation, and test

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, machine-learning

I have a dictionary which consists of all of the data read from a file. Dictionary has three keys:

1. name
2. seq
3. seq_len

Each of these keys correspond to a list so I have a dictionary of lists for example:

```
dictionary = {'name':['seq1','seq2','seq3','seq4',...,'seq10000'],
             'seq':['actatsts','gfsfsfsg','gstfdh','gsydg',...,'hdbcjshy'],
              'seq_len':[8,8,6,5,...,8]}
```

Now I want to split this dictionary in unison such that I end up getting dictionary for training, validation and test whereby 80%. How can I achieve that using dictionary data structure? Because I can't use sklearn train_test_split here. Insights would be appreciated.

Comment: have you considered using pandas?

Comment: Have the data as lists, numpy array or even pandas dataframes and you could use [this function here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to do the split

Comment: Yes, initially I had my names, seq and seq_len as lists. But I can only split these lists separately and not in unison, right? Is there a cleaner way to do this. That's why I decided to make a dictionary of lists thinking that it'll be easier to split a dictionary.

Comment: the `train_test_split` function will separate them in unison/altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_test_split(list(dictionary.values()),train_size = 0.8)
```

Although it will be great if you use pandas instead of lists.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
train_test_split(df,train_size = 0.8)
```

Comment: Thanks. I used pandas and got my three sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```py
# Way 1
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
train_val = df.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=42)
# `how='all'` if there are missing values in your raw data.
test = df[~df.isin(train_val)].dropna(how='all')


# Way 2
np.random.seed(42)

length = len(dictionary['name'])
new_index = np.random.permutation(length)

train_val_index = new_index[:int(length*0.8)]
test_index = list(set(new_index) - set(train_val_index))
train_val = {key: [value[i] for i in train_val_index] for key, value in dictionary.items()}
test = {key: [value[i] for i in test_index] for key, value in dictionary.items()}
```

I hope this will help you.